# How, in CSS, can you create a relative width depending on the height?

Tags: css, height, width, aspect-ratio

So I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="square">
        <div class="aspect-ratio"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="label">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box
{
    position   : relative;
    width      : 100%;
    background : red;
}

.square
{
    position   : absolute;
    left       : 0px;
    top        : 0px;

    width      : auto; // Needs to contain square aspect ratio depending on the height.
    height     : 100%;

    background : blue;
}

.label
{
    padding   : 20px;
    font-size : 14px;
}
```

Comment: You can't. You can do the opposite (`padding-top:x%` where x is the ratio) but not this.

Comment: Yea I know about the padding-top solution for relative height, but I got stuck to create the same solution for relative width. you are confirming my worries.

Comment: calc() is a new feature and very difficult to get cross-browser support.